# Why are drivers not working in Windows 10 with bootcamp?

Tags: bootcamp, macos, windows, thunderbolt

My colleague has two MacBook Pro 13 (Retina) laptops and has setup Windows 10 through bootcamp on both. The bootcamp wizard has been installed on both but there is a problem with the Thunderbolt drivers on one of them. When an external display is connected via Thunderbolt, it does not display anything until the machine is rebooted. There is a USB device in device manager that has an issue "set address failed" which we suspect is related to the problem.

The hardware is not quite identical... the problem machine is a 2014 MacBook Pro whilst the one that works is a 2015 MacBook Pro. Both are running El Capitan.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case it helps others, I got a response from Apple that it just isn't supported on the 2014 MacBook Pro. Another user on the Apple forum (https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7419574) has confirmed this on his 2014 MacBook Pro.

This post (http://forums.macrumors.com/threads/thunderbolt-hotplug-on-windows-10.1819920/) suggests that it works on a limited number of 2014 Mac computers but not all as the official FAQ suggests.